# How to handle event payments that include contributions

Tags: civievent

Sometimes we have situations where someone will pay for an event with a check and add a donation to the amount. 
How can I record a contribution and event payment in civi that was made with the same check?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event payment will create a contribution. To add a donation to the event payment form I suggest you look at pricesets. There you can add a donation field. http://gitbook.civicrm.org/events/complex-event-fees.html